# How do I link constraint data between objects?

Tags: constraints, linked-data

Normally if I have a material and want to put that material on say, 50 different objects, then I would select one object with that material, and then select the rest of the objects, hit Ctrl + L, and the material data would be copied to all the objects.

I have the exact situation I described above, except that I want to copy an object constraint from one object to all the other objects. Unfortunately the Ctrl + L menu doesn't have a "Constraints" button.

How do I copy this constraint to all the other objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select object/-s without constraint/-s first, object with them last, in *Object* > *Constraints* menu choose *Copy Constraints To Selected Objects*.

[image: copy constraints menu]

Answer (score 0):

Yuo need [copy attributes addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Copy_Attributes_Menu)

```
Ctrl+c
```

to activate it

[image: Copy attribute]